# Colors in preview

Tags: colors, preview, velo

I am experiencing an issue with the preview of my Wix website. I am creating a page for an association and have used the specific typography and colors from their brand image. In the Wix editor, everything looks as it should, with the correct typography and colors.

However, when I click on the preview button to see how the page will look in a browser, I notice that the colors of the page change. They do not remain true to the original colors of the association's brand image.

I would like to understand what could be the problem and how to resolve it. I would appreciate any guidance or advice you can provide to solve this issue and ensure that the colors remain consistent both in the editor and in the preview of the website. Thank you!

I have invested a significant amount of time and effort trying to resolve the issue with the colors on my Wix website. After noticing that the colors were changing in the preview, I attempted to modify them again in the Wix editor. I made sure to select the correct colors from the association's brand image.

Next, I proceeded to refresh the page, thinking that it might be necessary to refresh the changes to take effect. However, even after refreshing the page, the colors continued to display incorrectly in the preview.

In an effort to troubleshoot the problem, I decided to log out of my Wix account and then log back in. I thought this might help reset any settings or cache that could be causing the color changes. Unfortunately, even after doing this, the problem persisted, and the colors were not displayed correctly in the preview.

To find a solution, I searched for tutorials and guides on various social media platforms and video platforms. I followed the steps recommended by other users who had experienced similar issues, but none of those approaches seemed to solve my specific problem.

I even consulted with colleagues and friends who have experience using Wix, hoping they might provide some helpful advice or suggestions. Unfortunately, nobody was able to offer a clear solution or identify the exact cause of the problem.

In summary, I have tried a variety of methods to resolve the issue with the colors on my Wix website. From modifying the colors in the editor, to refreshing the page, logging out and logging back in, to seeking help in tutorials and consulting with other users. However, so far, I have not been able to find a solution that effectively solves the problem.